# How to read command line inputs using a C program

Tags: c, command-line

How to read command line inputs using a C program.
**by command line inputs, I don't mean command line arguments!!**

example: 
* I have a text file 'inputfile.txt' with few lines of names.
* Assume my program name is names.exe.
* I have to run the program using windows command line using following command:
    c:>names.exe < inputfile.txt

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's redirecting standard input, so in your program you don't do anything special at all -- you just read from standard input and write to standard output. If the user has redirected those, so be it.

Comment: Thanks Jerry. Your answer made me realize what to do.

Comment: I just used scanf, or gets. That was what I want.

Comment: Believe me, `gets` is *not* what you want -- ever. `scanf` is fine with some care, but even when you're reading from standard input, you want to use `fgets` instead of `gets` -- along with letting you specify a file, it lets you specify the size of buffer you're reading into. Using `gets`, you have no way to limit the data to the amount of space you allocated.

Answer (score 4):

Read from the `stdin` `FILE*`.

Comment: I think to read from file, I have to use the file name as an argument. But the way I have described is different. The command line sends the content of the file to the names.exe program.

Comment: May be you are right, but I understood the idea from Jerry Coffin's answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That instructs the system to replace your stdin file descriptor with a file descriptor to inputfile.txt. So just read from stdin like normal.

Answer (score 0):

For your example, the input is going to come on the standard input.  Just use `fread` or `fgets`.